# Setting root back to default status

Tags: password, root, user-management

Based on Ubuntu online documentation, the administrative root account is initially disabled by default by giving it a password that matches no possible encrypted value.

I mistakenly gave my root account a password and would like to place it back into a disabled state. I've used the following command:

```
sudo usermod -e 1 root
```

Is this the right way to do what I wanted to do?

(Note that I don't just want to lock the root account, which if I'm not mistaken, would be: `sudo passwd -l root`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically no.  What you have done is mark the account as expired, but it still has the same password.  `passwd -l` modifies the password hash by prefixing it with, iirc, an exclamation point.  That prevents any password from matching the hash, but the exclamation point can easily be removed to unlock the account and restore its previous password.

Either method has the effect of preventing anyone from logging in as root, so practically speaking, you are good.

Answer (score 0):

I also found some additional details from the Ubuntu 16.04 Manual, under options for the passwd command:

> -l, --lock. Lock the password of the named account. This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted  value (it adds a ´!´ at the beginning of the password).
>
> Note that this does not disable the account. The user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key).
>   To disable the account, administrators should use: usermod --expiredate 1. (this sets the account's expire date to Jan 2, 1970).